# Mapa mostrando local de procura swift

Tags: swift, xcode, mapkit

Galera, gostaria de saber como posso fazer com que o meu mapa mostre o lugar que foi procurado e centre o view neste ponto. Consegui fazer com a localização atual da seguinte forma:

```
self.mapDisplay.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingMode.Follow, animated: true) //Linha de seguir o mapa
```

Porém eu preciso com o resultado do endereço pesquisado, o que eu deveria usar?

Update 1:

Primeiro eu criei um Geocoder:

```
var geocoder = CLGeocoder()
```

Depois usei o método de buscar uma string de endereço e colocar na variável placemark. E usando as propriedades disponíveis nessa variável usei o placemark.location.coordinate.latitude e o placemark.location.coordinate.longitute:

```
 geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address,{(placemarks: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if let placemark = placemarks?[0] as? CLPlacemark { 

 let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: placemark.location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: placemark.location.coordinate.longitude)
                    self.mapView.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location, 350, 350)
                    self.mapView.centerCoordinate = location

}
```

Comment: Você já possui esse método de encontrar as coordenadas a partir do endereço ou é a partir daí que você precisa?

Comment: É a partir dai que eu preciso, eu não possuo o método.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como fazer o mapa mostrar local de procura usando coordenadas sem api externo

Primeiro eu criei um Geocoder:

```
var geocoder = CLGeocoder()
```

Depois usei o método de buscar uma string de endereço e colocar na variável placemark. E usando as propriedades disponíveis nessa variável usei o

```
placemark.location.coordinate.latitude e o placemark.location.coordinate.longitute:

 geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address,{(placemarks: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if let placemark = placemarks?[0] as? CLPlacemark { 

 let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: placemark.location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: placemark.location.coordinate.longitude)
                    self.mapView.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location, 350, 350)
                    self.mapView.centerCoordinate = location

}
```

Comment: Se essa é a solução correta marque ela

Answer (score 1):

Bom, como você precisa primeiro encontrar ainda as coordenadas, talvez a resposta seja um pouco ampla, mas resumindo, no próprio *iOS* não existe um método que você passe o endereço e ele te retorne latitude e longitude então você precisa primeiro buscar uma alternativa, como o [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=pt-br).

Basicamente consiste em você passar um endereço e receber um *JSON*, que possui vários parâmetros e dentre eles a latitude e longitude. Por exemplo:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Av+Paulista+4000,+Sao+Paulo,+SP&sensor=true
```

Se você acessar esse endereço vai encontrar os parâmetros que precisa e com eles em mãos (após fazer uma requisição com `NSURLConnection` e etc), para centralizar este ponto no mapa, crie o objeto `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, defina a região e então aponte o centro. Assim:

```
let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)

mapDisplay.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location, 900, 900)
mapDisplay.centerCoordinate = location
```

Bom, é basicamente esse o caminho que você deve tomar. Se precisar de mais detalhes quanto à requisição, você pode fazer uma busca ou criar outra pergunta, acredito que já existem alguns bons exemplos com esse tipo de requisição de serviço.

Para colocar um marcador no mapa, é algo assim:

```
let annotation: MKPointAnnotation! = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = location

mapDisplay.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

Comment: Mas sem usar o googleapi qual seria o método caso eu tivesse as coordenadas?

Comment: Já com as coordenadas, é só usar esse código, onde `lat` e `lng` na primeira linha são os seus valores em double, que vai centralizar o mapa.

Comment: Consegui sem precisar o google api, irei demostrar meu procedimento quando eu editar a pergunta.

Comment: Tem razão, é possível mesmo obter as coordenadas sem utilizar serviço externo. Erro meu, sua solução é melhor mesmo.

Comment: Brigado, mas não seria possivel sem sua ajuda! Tem algum jeito de colocar agora um "alfinete" nessa cordenada?

Comment: Sim, bem simples. Fiz uma edição na minha resposta sobre como adicionar um marcador.

Comment: @Skal Você poderia postar sua solução para o geocoding como resposta, em vez de deixar na própria pergunta? É mais condizente com o formato do site, e deve ajudar outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida. Obrigado!